# IncompatibleClassChangeError in sphinx4 while trying WSJ jar

Tags: java, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am trying to use Sphinx-4 prealpha release for speech recognition, but I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet, but interface was expected
at edu.cmu.sphinx.model.acoustic.WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.Model.newProperties(Model.java:158)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:518)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(PropertySheet.java:296)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist.newProperties(FlatLinguist.java:221)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:518)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(PropertySheet.java:296)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.newProperties(SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:177)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:518)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(PropertySheet.java:296)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.AbstractDecoder.newProperties(AbstractDecoder.java:81)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.Decoder.newProperties(Decoder.java:36)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:518)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(PropertySheet.java:296)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.newProperties(Recognizer.java:86)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:518)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(ConfigurationManager.java:163)
```

at recogniser line:

```
ConfigurationManager cm = new ConfigurationManager(url);
    Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
```

I am using netbeans and have added 3 jar files in my project: 
sphinx4-core-5prealpha.jar 
sphinx4-data-5prealpha.jar 
WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz 
please help me resolving this error.
Thanks

Comment: You mix old code with old jars. You need to follow the tutorial instead, you only need sphinx4-core and sphinx4-data. http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4